# How to manually mount and unmount USB storage device in U-boot?

Tags: usb, embedded-linux, u-boot

Can anyone share how to manually mount and unmount USB storage device in U-boot?

I need to program the u-boot to search for a file in the USB.
The USB will be having fat file system.
I want to search for a image and load the image and then execute it. Its a small firmware/executable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

U-boot doesn't really have a concept of mounting filesystems, so it also can't unmount them.

Comment: Thanks kristof. How can i search for a file in USB storage device while in U-boot prompt? I thought that required mounting the file system first :s

Comment: It does, in Linux (or any other Unix), but U-boot is not Linux. I don't know if U-boot even supports listing files. The version I have here doesn't appear to support it for ext2 in any case.

Comment: The USB will be having fat file system in it not ext2. I want to search for a image and load the image and then execute it. Its a small firmware/executable.

Comment: i found the answer. it is usb start and usb stop

Comment: usb start and usb stop start and stop the USB drivers. It does not mount or unmount filesystems.